# My django app on heroku is running but logs says it is crashed

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have a django app running on heroku.

It is online, and I can access it and it is working on http://demo.dagenssalg.dk

But I can't submit changes to it, and in the log it says it is chrashed.

```
Feb 02 07:17:17 dagenssalg app/web.1: ImportError: bad magic number in 'form.admin': b'\x03\xf3\r\n' 
Feb 02 07:17:17 dagenssalg app/web.1: [2018-02-02 15:17:17 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9) 
Feb 02 07:17:17 dagenssalg app/web.1: [2018-02-02 15:17:17 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8) 
Feb 02 07:17:17 dagenssalg app/web.1: [2018-02-02 15:17:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master 
Feb 02 07:17:17 dagenssalg app/web.1: [2018-02-02 15:17:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot. 
Feb 02 07:17:17 dagenssalg heroku/web.1: Process exited with status 3 
Feb 02 07:17:18 dagenssalg heroku/web.1: State changed from up to crashed
```

What am I missing? 
Any help is most appreciated.
Best regards
Kresten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that somehow UNIX magic number was damaged in your python compiled files.

On the linux inside project you can fix following by deleting compiled files

```
find . -name \*.pyc -delete
```

EDIT ---

See if .pyc is not in your git repo as following could produce same result on heroku